# Flask-SQLAlchemy: How to query according to User's role and team?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am able to list the users as reviewer with `Role.id == 4`, and can be selected by the current user:

```
def reviewer_choices():
    return User.query.join(User.roles).filter(Role.id == 4)

form_extra_fields = {
     'reviewer1': sqla.fields.QuerySelectField(
      label='Reviewer1',
      query_factory=reviewer1_choices,
)}
```

Now, how can I query the users are with `Role.id == 4` and `Team.id ==
  current_user.teams.id`? (Restrict reviewer and current user are **with same team**)

I've tried below but in vain:

```
User.query.join(User.roles).join(User.teams).
     filter(Role.id == 4).filter(Team.id = current_user.teams.id)
```

The classes are defined as below, thanks:

```
class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Team(db.Model, RoleMixin):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
     description = db.Column(db.String(255))

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                         backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
     teams = db.relationship('Team', secondary=teams_users,uselist=False,
                        backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
     email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.email

class Project(db.Model):

     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     reviewer = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))

     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

You should define your User model as follows:

```
# -> 1. many to one

class User(db.Model):
    # ...
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("team.id"))
    team = db.relationship("Team", foreign_keys=team_id)
    # ...

User.query.filter(Role.id == 4, Team.id == current_user.team_id).all()

# -> 2. one to one

class User(db.Model):
    # ...
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("team.id"))
    team = db.relationship("Team", foreign_keys=team_id, uselist=False)
    # ...

User.query.filter(Role.id == 4, Team.id == current_user.team_id).all()

# -> 3. many to many 

users_teams = db.Table(db.Column("user_id", db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("user.id"),
                       db.Column("role_id", db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("team.id"))

class User(db.Model):
    # ...
    teams = db.relationship("Team", secondary=users_teams)
    # ...

User.query.filter(Role.id == 4, User.teams.any(Team.id.in_([team.id for team in current_user.teams]))).all()
```

`uselist` is used to define a one to one relationship.

`secondary` is used to define many to many relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the error occured: `TypeError: 'Team' object is not iterable`

Comment: I use the basic model define of Flask-Security. `User.query.filter(User.roles.any(Role.id.in_([1,2]))).all()
` works.

Comment: I know. You use `uselist=False` in the define of relationship of teams in User . What's the relation between `Team` and `User`? many to one or many to many?

Comment: The relation between `Team` and `User` is one to one. Each user only belongs to one team.

Comment: I think it might be many to one. many users belong to one team.

Comment: Yes you are right. I used`return User.query.join(User.roles).join(User.teams).filter(Role.id == 4).filter(Team.id == current_user.teams.id)` and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: But the define of teams in User model is not correct in semantic.

Comment: Do you mean the `uselist=False`? I am not quite sure I understand you correctly. Thanks.

Comment: See my updated answer. It provide a correct define of relationship between User and Team.

Comment: Yes I see your update. I added `uselist=False` to make `User` and `Team` to make it become many to one relationship.  What made me very confused is that even I added `uselist=False` to `User` and `Role` then the error occured: `TypeError: 'Role' object is not iterable`. But their code are the same, which confused me for a long time.

Comment: `uselist=False` define a one to one relationship.

Comment: @The updated answer is very clear and the select field shows correct. but when I tried to save it, the error occured: `sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError
InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 8 - probably unsupported type. `  Would you please advise what might be happened?